# How can I edit tooltips for unity launcher icons

Tags: unity, tooltip

I want to change the tooltips for some icons in unity launcher. Is there any way we can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unity launcher icons are defined by *.desktop* files - usually from `/usr/share/applications`.

The tooltip is the *Name=* section in this file - for example, the default *seahorse.desktop* file looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Passwords and Encryption Keys
Comment=Manage your passwords and encryption keys
Exec=seahorse
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=seahorse
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Security;Settings;
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=seahorse
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.32.0
X-GNOME-DocPath=seahorse/seahorse.xml
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=seahorse
```

To change the tooltip on a per user basis, copy the desktop file to your local applications folder i.e.

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
cp /usr/share/applications/seahorse.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then edit this file with you favourite editor and change the `Name=` value for example

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/seahorse.desktop
```

In the image I've changed `Name=` to be:

```
Name=my new tooltip
```

Open Nautilus and browse to the folder `~/.local/share/applications` and drag and drop `seahorse.desktop` to the launcher

[image]