# how to remove tooltip message feature from all of Ubuntu 12.04 desktop and user applications?

Tags: configuration, tooltip

I searched and not able to find a way to do this.

I find this very annoying. After installing 12.04, I keep getting these tooltip messages from all the applications I use. I want to remove this feature.

For example, now when I move the mouse to launcher near an icon, the toolip message (black background and white font) comes up. I do not want this to show.

I am using the default desktop after installing 12.04 (I think this is called unity).

Here is an answer that shows how to edit a configuration file to change the message itself. But I really want to disable this feature from all applications. Do I have to go edit configurations files to do this?

[How can i edit tooltips for unity launcher icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91593/how-can-i-edit-tooltips-for-unity-launcher-icons)

Here is a screen shot from my desktop showing a tooltip when using firefox. Such tooltips show up in every application I open !

You can see how annoying they are and they get in the way.

[image]
thanks

**update:**

I found a way to disable tooltip in firefox, using

> about:config

and then search for the word tip and make it false.

I hope that I do not have to do this for each application that I use now. It seems every application I use have tooltips enabled on Ubuntu (such as gedit, Libre office software, thunderbird, etc...).  On windows, I did not have this problem with these applications. I noticed these tooltips on these applications only on 12.04, that is why I thought it is a configuration feature on 12.04.

I thought there might be a global option to disable tooltips for all applications. May be there is not.

But the point remains, I'd really like to turn off these tooltips for the desktop itself. Like on the launcher and other places on the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooltips annoy me too! Here's what I did to get rid of them.

1. Install Compizconfig Settings Manager

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Enable the *Opacity, Brightness, and Saturation* plugin
3. Click the <kbd>New</kbd> button and add a *Tooltip* rule as follows:

[image]

- Optional: for awesome slightly transparent right click, drop-down, and app-indicators, make a rule like I have (just above my Tooltip rule), and specify the opacity as 90.