# Why is the tooltip hiding Dash Search on 12.04?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, tooltip

Can I disable the tooltip shown at the side of the Launcher icon when hovered by the mouse. These are nice, but I want to disable them, because when I press "Dash Home" button on the launcher, then want to write something on the dash, I can't see the letters because of the tooltip.

How can I disable the Unity tooltip from hiding search string in dash? I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have given a screenshot of the launcher. My problem is basically with this

[image]

---

#### Update 1

I have given advice to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/149721/61218) in chat discussion, but nothing has changed.

---

#### Update 2

As an answer suggests, I updated unity to the latest version. It is now unity 5.12.0.
as the below output indicates

```
$ unity --version
unity 5.12.0
```

Comment: I don't see that problem in Unity 3D: see [this screenshot](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1340948084.png). What are you running? That doesn't look like the default launcher icon either...

Comment: @izx, I am running Unity 3D in Edubuntu. I also have Ubuntu installed with Unity 3D. But both are same. Only the icon is different

Comment: Can you take a screenshot with *Shutter*, with the *Capture Cursor* option enabled? I'm just confused because this behavior [was a bug, but was fixed before 11.10](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFIQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbugs.launchpad.net%2Fbugs%2F747593&ei=OzztT8PGKcqK2gWYxKjhCg&usg=AFQjCNFwN9C_xMVlEHCvbr_u4KBCxjPpwQ&sig2=zkYBaz3nb7xqpXBO_Gvumw&cad=rja).

Comment: @izx, I have updated the screenshot, with *capture cursor* enabled.

Comment: Are you installing Unity 3D from external PPA, or From Ubuntu Repositories. Because frankly this doesn't happens in Ubuntu Unity 3D Dash Bar.

Comment: @tijybba Thanks, But this is happening in my Laptop with default installation. The iso is downloaded from Ubuntu site. And didn't install anything from PPA

Comment: Have you done Updating after fresh install , since Unity has been updated twice (i guess) since release. This also enriches me to ask a new question, are the iso images updated . I guess i will post it as new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried using the Live USB , your mentioned problem persists in Default Ubuntu 12.04 Unity  (5.10.0-0ubuntu6) release, well you need to do a **System update** where  currently Unity is updated to unity (5.12-0ubuntu1.1).

You can refer the [Change Log](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/unity/unity_5.12-0ubuntu1.1/changelog), which states

**Dash - Make statefulness of Dash Home and Dash Lenses consistent (LP: #914759))**

**Dash - Remove Dash Home shortcut icons (LP: #885738)**

**Dash text input does not get focus (LP: #774447)**

**Note**:
According to confirmed bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/978030)

This bug was fixed in the package unity - 5.12-0ubuntu1.1 unity (12-0ubuntu1.1) precise-proposed; urgency=low

- Cherry pick upstream fixes.

  - Fix UnityViewWindow background when blur is disabled (LP: #989291)
  - App icon on the Unity Launcher lost track of running
    instance (LP: #772063)
  - No launcher icon or Alt+Tab entry for Gimp windows (LP: #995916)
  - Locked smuxi launcher icon does not indicate smuxi running
    status (LP: #999820)
  - **Fix dash search field hidden by tooltips (LP: #978030)**
  - Launcher is silent to screen reader users (LP: #949448)
  - Fix 3D apps running much slower under Unity (LP: #987304)
  - Reduced number of calls to ResultViewGrid::QueueDraw
  - Reduced number of calls to BGHash::RefreshColor
    -- Alan Pope  Wed, 23 May 2012 18:10:49 +0100

  I guess for it to work , you will have to Enable the **Precise-proposed** [repository](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) option from Software Source in Update column.

Comment: Try rebooting or resetting Unity.

Comment: Awesome find, @tijybba! **`precise-updates` has the update** - proposed is not needed. Anwar, make sure you have `precise-updates` in your `sources.list`, then do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` -- then reboot!

Comment: Yes !! Awesome work @tijybba. after resetting by `unity --reset` it worked! Thanks. @izx thanks you also