# How do I remove the tool tips on the launch bar?

Tags: launcher, tooltip

The title is the question. These tool tips stay until I try to click past them. They're annoying since they constantly pop up and block the view of what I'm trying to do.  Unfortunately I need the launch bar because Ubuntu is running on VMware and the console does not allow me to use the keyboard for switching tasks (to my knowledge). How do I disable them?

I'd post an image as an example, but this site will not let me.

UPDATE:
unity 5.16.0

UPDATE 2: I discovered that this may only be a problem with users who run Ubuntu on a full screen VMware console that is situated on the right monitor.  When the mouse is moved to the left monitor the tooltips popup and remain until the mouse is clicked twice in the VMware console window to make it active.

Unfortunately my problem is one involving a rare situation I think. However, I'd love to be able to disable these tool tips if possible.  It would also be nice if new features were added that can allow further customization of the launch bar.

Comment: You can give a link to the image though

Comment: Check this question whether they are related or even same problem http://askubuntu.com/q/157441/61218

Comment: Here is the screenshot of what I mean: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14464971/Images/annoyingtooltip.PNG And no I don't know if that other question is exactly what I am referring to. It doesn't appear to have an answer that makes any actionable sense. I'm on Ubuntu 12 Server and it as well as Unity is up to date.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering it the hard way to remove the tool tip

Tool tips are mentioned in **.desktop** file located under **/usr/share/applications**

Sample .desktop file

```
$cat pidgin.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Pidgin Internet Messenger
GenericName=Internet Messenger
Comment=Chat over IM.  Supports AIM, Google Talk, Jabber/XMPP, MSN, Yahoo and more
Exec=pidgin
Icon=pidgin
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=pidgin
```

Tool tip come from the option **Name=Pidgin Internet Messenger** . If you make Name to null ("**Name=**") tool tip will not appear.

Take a backup of all the files under **/usr/share/applications**

use Perl one-liner to change multiple files.(Recommended to change only the files that are currently in your launcher)

```
 perl -p -i -e 's/Name=.*/Name=/g' `find . -name *.desktop`
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, good stuff to know as a last resort, but I definitely would rather wait to see if I get a less tedious, all in one solution if possible.

Comment: Yes, even I would suggest you to wait until some AskUbuntu experts review and advice.