# Minimize tool tip not disappearing

Tags: 12.04, tooltip

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The tool tips for the Minimize button do not disappear when a window is Maximized. The problem happens when the mouse pointer hovers over the Minimize button while the window is maximizing. The solution I'm using now is to not let the pointer near the minimize button.

[image: The mouse pointer hovering near the minimize button]

[image: The result after maximizing]

Is there any way to avoid this? May be increase the amount of time required for a tool tip to appear. Or to remove tool tips for these buttons, as they're pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/149721/58990), you can make tool tip transparent! This is a quick workaround for disabling tool tips.

[image: Disable tool tip]

Comment: Thank you! But  is this the only way? Because I'd like to selectively hide the tool tips for the close, maximize and minimize buttons.